# How to add Drives shortcut link to Folder View widget in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu

How can i add shortcut links to my drives(disk) shortcut link to folder view widget in Kubuntu. I want to add these shortcut links because i can directly go to my drives without selecting dolphine from start menu.

What i have done so far

-Inside folder view widget i clicked 3rd mouse key and selected

```
Create New>> Basic link to file or directory
```

Then i selected the drives(disk) path and made a link to the disk in folder view widget.

[image]

But the problem is whenever i restart the system those shortcut links are not working anymore and again i have to make a new shortcut link for the drives.

can you tell me how i can make a shortcut links in it, i am a noob in kubuntu

Answer (score 1):

In the folder view preferences you can change the default folder
which is presented. Right now I am not using KDE, but depending on
the version of Kubuntu you are using you can set the default folder
to be `/media` or `/media/your-user-name` (assuming that it is in one
of these folders your drives are mounted).

If you do this correctly the folder view will show the list of the drives
mounted in `/media` (or `/media/your-user-name`).

By the way, you can access the folder view preferences clicking the little wrench
that appears when you hover the pointer around the edges of the folder view.